# Calling awakeFromNib() in prepareForInterfaceBuilder()

Tags: ios, swift

I am subclassing UIButton and want my custom button to appear in Storyboard. I made all my changes in `awakeFromNib()` (called its super) and added `@IBDesignable`.

```
override func awakeFromNib(){
   super.awakeFromNib()
   ... // customization stuff
}
```

And in `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` i need to use what i did in `awakeFromNib()`, so if i call `awakeFromNib()` directly, will it cause any bad stuff to happen? If yes, what will it cause? Or it is totally fine? Like this:

```
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder(){
    ...
    self.awakeFromNib()
}
```

Or do i have to create a `setup()` function with all my customization inside, and then call it from both awake and prepare functions?

Thanks.

Comment: “so if i call awakeFromNib() directly” No. Never do that. It is an event. It is not yours to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should combine code in a method (as you mentioned `setup()` let's say) and call it in both `awakeFromNib()` and `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` instead of calling `awakeFromNib()` manually.

`awakeFromNib` is one of the view life cycle methods, meaning that it should get called by the system at a particular status. Avoid call such a method by yourself; What you should do is to provide the needed functionality to be performed when `awakeFromNib` get called but *not* calling it by yourself.

> in Apple documentation about awakeFromNib() it says "Although the
>   default implementation of this method does nothing, many UIKit classes
>   provide non-empty implementations.". So if it does nothing, what can
>   calling it cause?

First, you should take a look for the second part of the sentence:

> many UIKit classes provide non-empty implementations.

Which means that there is a specific code should get run (in `super. awakeFromNib`):

> You must call the super implementation of awakeFromNib to give parent
>   classes the opportunity to perform any additional initialization they
>   require.

Second, even if there is no harm from doing it, you should not do it, you should not follow the approach of calling a method that gets called by the system.